# How can I export contacts with unicode characters from Outlook 2013

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I have some contacts with Chinese names and when I do the following sequence of steps to generate a CSV file, it prints out ??? in place where the Chinese characters are.
File -> Open & Export
Select Import / Export
Select Export to a file
Select Common Separated Values (no Excel)
Select Contact folder to export from
....

I have searched online and it appears with Outlook 2010 there is an option to save as an Excel format rather than a CSV format.  I have also tried changing my default system language to Chinese.  However neither makes any differences.

Can someone advise what can be done to export non English characters from Outlook 2013?

Thanks.

Comment: I tried it and it works for me right away. Can it be that the resulting file *is* in Unicode, but the *program* you use to display the file cannot display it and produces the "???" ?

Comment: @Aganju, I don't think so because I tried opening it in Notes and I still see garbled characters.  In fact I have changed my Windows default language to be Chinese and it's now outputting something like ¤ßÅ¦¬ì.

I've also tried changing to use Unicode UTF-8 under Advanced -> International options but no help here either.

It is strange that it works for you.  Can you let me know which version of Windows and Outlook you are using, and what is your default language?

Answer (score 0):

Okay believe it or not if you import the CSV with the corrupted characters they magically would be rendered properly in Outlook.

Obviously please take a backup of the Outlook data file first before doing so.

Answer (score 0):

The best confirmed way is to use an android mobile to do that. I hope you have one :)

1. On Android, add your email account having the contacts, and make sure you select to sync contacts as well. this is the default settings when you add
   an account.
2. open contacts in android, and make sure you select to
   show only contacts from that new account (this is available in
   contact settings).
3. from the contact settings on the phone, you will
   have an option to export contacts to the phone storage, just do it.
4. from the settings, you have also an option to import contacts.
   however, when you select to import, it will ask you to which account
   you need to import. here select your google account. if it asks, select
   the file you already export. however most of the phones will not ask
   you for a specific file, and it will find immediately the exported
   file.
5. Wait couples of minutes to allow the sync process to finish,
   or you can force it to start from the account settings in android.
6. use export tools from google, it allows any encoding.
7. Have fun.